# tensorflow: find larges value in variable and replace it

Tags: python, tensorflow, softmax

I have a `tf.Variable()` came out of softmax, as a sequence of probabilities, e.g., `[0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2]`. What I tried to do is to convert this sequence into [0, 0, 1, 0, 0], i.e. the highest probability replaced with 1 and all other with 0. But since `tf.Variable()` is not iterative, and `tf.reduce_max()` only gives the largest value itself, how can I do this?

Comment: with a simple list comprehension : `[1 if x == max(a) else 0 for x in a]`

Comment: the thing is tensorflow variable seems to be not iterative so I think you can enumerate each value in the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf

tf.enable_eager_execution()
softmax = tf.constant([0.3, 0.5, 0.8, 0.1, 0.2], dtype=tf.float32)
index = tf.argmax(softmax, axis=0, output_type=tf.int32)

# sparse = tf.SparseTensor(tf.reshape(index, [-1]), tf.constant([[1]], dtype=tf.int32), tf.shape(softmax))
result = tf.scatter_nd(tf.expand_dims(tf.expand_dims(index, axis=0), axis=0), tf.constant([1], dtype=tf.int32),
                       shape=tf.shape(softmax))
```